# htaccess rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a site with urls mysite.com/?p=605, I want any URLs containing /?p=123 to be rewritten to mysite.com/remap.php?page_id=123 with a 301. Can anyone provide a simply rewrite for this please?

Thanks in advance for your help.

John

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p\=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^$ /remap.php?page_id=%1 [R=301,L]
```

should work

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the post. I had hoped I could get it in without conflict with the other rewrites, but this is not the case. I have a rewrite rule to RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f Can you think of a way to stop it conflicting?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

Comment: Your given, two rewrite rules makes no sense for me. You just remove them, as the only thing they are doing - replicating default apache behaviour, for PHP - load index.php/index.html for directory URL's. Additionally, if you noticed "L" flag in the end of rules - that means, if that rule is triggered, it will stop matching process, and wont try to match rules that are lower in access file.